# How to change default install path for Notepad++ in Powershell silent/unattended script

Tags: powershell, scripting, installation

I cant figure out the parameter(s) to change the default install path `C:\Program Files\` of Notepad++ to the drive I want it to install to when I run my PowerShell script. I am trying to do a silent install and can't change it manually.

Does anyone know what parameters I can add to install the program to the `E:` drive?

Below is my code and what I am trying in PowerShell. I have been messing around a lot with the `-ArgumentList` parameters to figure out if I can point it to the `E:` drive but no luck so far. I am running this on Windows Server 2012 also.

```
function install-Notepadpp()
{
    $install="*PATH*\npp.6.6.2.Installer.exe"
    Start-Process -FilePath $install -ArgumentList '/InstallDirectoryPath:"E:\"','/S'  -Wait -Verb RunAs  
    Write-Host "Notepad++ has been installed." -ForegroundColor Green
}

##### This is Windows calling the function to install the script
install-Notepadpp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really require an installation? You have the standalone package out there on dev site, you can copy it wherever you want. As for the 'cool' context menu addons, they are simple enough to add manually.

Below is the brief description of steps you need to take to get this done:

- Have your Powershell copy the content of standalone package to the
  desired folder.
- Generate a new GUID using Powershell

  [guid]::NewGUID()
- Write down the GUID to variable (so you can reference it later).
- Under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\ add GUID entry in the same way the
  rest of GUIDs are added.
- Create a subcontainers *InprocServer32* and *Settings*
- In the *InprocServer32* set the *(Default)* value to desired
  Notepad++ installation path pointing directly to NppShell_06.dll (ex.
  C:\Program Files\Notepad++\NppShell_06.dll)
- Add *ThreadingModel* REG_SZ entry and set its' value to *Apartment*
- In the *Settings* subcontainer, set the values accordingly - for a
  list of valid values, please reference a machine with Notepad++
  installed. The most "interesting" ones are "Path" and "Title"
- Add the GUID entry you generated earlier to subcontainer "ANotepad++"
  in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\ under *(Default)*
  value

This should do it. Although I did not test the above on my machine, I am pretty confident that this will sort out the "manual" installation issue. As a sidenote, it could be worth as a suggestion to developer (or, as a best way, write it on your own!) to add some silent installation configuration switches so that we don't have to bother with the above 'workarounds'. Should you run into some issues setting this up, let me know.

Comment: I have to automate specific .exe programs into a silent install for multiple installs to numerous virtual machines (VMs). That is why any manual interaction cant take place, as for me being a developer, i have tried almost all silent install switches and cant figure it out. which is why i posted on the forum. I tried your method and it worked (thank you!) but cant be used practically in my enviroment. Ive tried modifying my system enviroment variables (such as Program Files,Program Files(x86), Common Program Files, and Common Program Files(x86) to the E:\) but still no success.

Comment: Please then post a proper question - your question asked on how to install notepad++, whereas it did not state that you have other programs that you can't install.
If you are a developer, then you surely understand that each installation executable can be designed independently - exception goes for .msi packages which are complaint to microsoft standard and should have a silent install switch. Else you need to figure out the silent installation on your own for each program which is different. As for Np++ - you can write a script that does all that automatically regardless of computer...

Comment: "As for Np++ - you can write a script that does all that automatically regardless of computer" that is exactly what i am asking in original post. I showed you my current code and don't understand how i can direct N++ to another drive within the code i've given. I cant find any new silent switches for it, nor do any enviromental variables ive tried worked to get it to install to the E:\. I am at a complete dead end

Comment: What I proposed is not a "silent installation" per se, but a workaround to automate notepad++ installations. In the answer I gave, you don't "install" the notepad++, you just copy it as standalone executable and tweak the registry to match your current desired state (ex. the paths). Adding the paths to the registry as I described above will make OS think that "notepad++" is genuinely installed. You stated it cannot be used in your environment - why so? The standalone np++ works just fine, and the registry tweaks are just to show the context menu...

Comment: True, a good workaround but i figured it out. I went into the registry and exported those .reg files that contained the default paths to the C:\ and changed them all to the E:\. Then i put all those .reg files i exported into a master .reg file and then called that through my script. Script was:                                                                   regedit.exe /S  nMaster.reg    thank you for your help

Comment: Thanks for thumbs up, glad I could help. See you around on SE and let me know if you have other questions, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 4):

Notepad++ installer uses NSIS installer system. You can leverage its default switches to accomplish that.

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Which_command_line_parameters_can_be_used_to_configure_installers

eg.: npp.6.6.8.Installer.exe /S /D=d:\software\npp

Note:/D option does not support quotes

Comment: Related: 
http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#silent

Answer (score 0):

True, a good workaround @Koliat but i figured it out. I went into the registry and exported those .reg files that contained the default paths to the C:\ and changed them all to the E:. Then i put all those .reg files i exported into a master .reg file and then called that through my script.

Script line was:

```
regedit.exe /S nMaster.reg
```

thank you for your help and pushing me into the right direction as far as taking the registry into account.